matplotlib plot dataframe with two columns, one is date, another one is text
This question could be simple to you but I couldn't figure out. I have a pandas dataframe with information of date column DATE and a text column LOC.
      DATE    LOC
2018-02-24  ANA#1
2020-06-01  ANH#2
2021-07-25  ANO#1
2022-09-16  ANS#2
2023-11-08  ANM#1

How to use matplotlib to put on a time-series graph with the LOC according to DATE? The Y-axis of the graph is something else. LOC is like annotation.

What do you mean by "put on a graph with the LOC according to DATE"? Can you [edit] your question to add a drawing of the expected graph?

X-axis is DATE, Y-axis is something else. The LOC is like annotation.

Then be explicit, explain what is "something else" if relevant and provide an explicit mockup graph to demonstrate what you want. Without this, the question should be closed as lacking details/clarity.

thanks for your help. but i can't put any image with my current network due to restriction policy set. the annotation position Y can be, says 1 for all the LOC. It doesn't depend on the Y value.  But each annotation LOC has to be according to the DATE.

Then you want to annotate
